# How to use NUnit TestCase with internal type as argument

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit

I have got stuck while writing some tests when wanted to use TestCase attribute with some parameters.

I wanted to specify multiple test cases with some inputs and outputs but one of it is of type that is Internal. To use it as a test method parameter the method itself needs to be at most internal, but then the NUnit executors are refusing to run such tests.

Are there any ways around this problem or is it just bad design?

Comment: Make the parameter type just `object` and cast in the method? Ugly, but should unblock you...

Comment: @JonSkeet Ugly but nice workaround anyway. Didn't came up with it.